# Open-Source alternative for Adobe Connect

Tags: open-source, web-apps, chat, collaboration, web-services

I wish to run a server and a service for holding some webinars and remote class. But for many reasons I prefer to just you open-source software or online services.

The features I am looking for are:

- A frame for live video cam
- A frame to present my slide
- a chat box
- a list to show who are online
- a voice override by the keynote speaker and the meeting manager
- boxes for file transfer (on to download and one to upload) from the manager and keynote speaker to attendees and vice versa.

also, some option would be necessary including but not limited to:

- the ability to ask questions and answering by attendees... maybe or may not be heard by others depending on the will/wish of the keynote speaker and/or meeting manager and could be replayed several times by meeting manager and keynote...

that would make it a nice option if we can

- swap between the live video cam and the slides (to save the space... one be a larger frame and the other be a smaller one)

Adobe Connect could be my perfect answer, but if it was open-source.

Is there any candidate to substitute Adobe Connect with that!?

Or, if there is no single software which can replace Adobe Connect, is there a combination of applications and services  which can team up and replace Adobe Connect.

I really want something like Adobe Connect, but I have to just use open source software and services.

Comment: The features I need are... a Video Panel... a file transfer a panel... a chat box... and a panel to check the presence... a feed that the meeting manager anounces his words... and ability to talk over the webinar by the main presenter and maybe by the manager...

Comment: You will most likely have to combine several tools because open-source is rarely bundled. Chances are community members will be able to name few ools at a time for each task. This question should NOT be placed on hold, because it is clear and on topic.